# How to style desktop menu width in WordPress?

Tags: html, css

I want my desktop menu to stretch half way across the page on selection.

Here is my menu html:

```
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div class="module-group right">
<div class="module left">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1- 
collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item- 
1496" class="menu-item menu-item-
type-post_type menu- 
item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item 
page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu-item- 
has-children menu-item-1496 dropdown active"><a 
title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a>. 
<span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data- 
toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></span>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1502" class="fa fa-user menu-item 
menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu- 
item-1502"><a title="Create Adsler Account" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/create-account/">Create 
Adsler Account</a></li>`
```

I tried

`@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 768px) {#menu {width: 50%}}`

This ties into another problem I'm having which is how to replace the parent menu item with just fa fa-bars So now it goes bars->home->angle down-main menu, whereas it should go - bars->main menu.

Html:

```
div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div class="module-group right">
<div class="module left">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1- 
collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item- 
1496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type 
menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu- 
item page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu- 
item-has-children menu-item-1496 dropdown active"><a 
title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a>. 
<span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data- 
toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></span>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1502" class="fa fa-user menu-item 
menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page
```

In connection to this, the menu isn't scrolling properly on desktop. https://adsler.co.uk

Comment: I've added the code to the fiddle and it seems to be working just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5vp0qbfu/ Is there something specific I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please see here on desktop https://adsler.co.uk. The menu only stretches out a little bit when clicked on desktop. This means icons and words are crushed together and you can't really see the whole menu. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it doesn't scroll properly

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example page you provided in the comments, I think you can try with:

```
#menu {
  left: calc(100% - 50vw);
  width: 50vw;
}
```

( in the @media if this should only be applied to specific screen size).

Currently, the menu won't stretch out because of the relatively positioned `menu-item` above it. The absolutely positioned element checks where its borders are based on the relatively positioned parent.

More on **vw** units:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp and
https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

More on position:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

(I hope that makes sense.)

Comment: What this seems to do is move `fa fa-angle-down` to the middle of the page and the menu itself to span the whole width. This ties into another problem I'm having which is how to replace the parent menu item with just `fa fa-bars` So now it goes bars->home->angle down-main menu, whereas it should go - bars->main menu. Haven't yet managed to fix. You can view here at https://adsler.co.uk

Comment: It's hard to help if there's just a description. If this issue if part of this problem, can you please update the code (html and css) if not you should proprably make another question. Thank you.